# Proving continuity of homotopy of clutching functions

Tags: vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

This is in [page 45 of Hatcher's, that there is a linear homotopy between clutchig functions](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) .

**I could not workout/justify the linear homotopy. Is there an easy way to see the continuity of homotopy?**

EDIT: I have found on [page 63](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/162450/files/karpova.semestre.hess2.pdf) of this homotopy. But I do not follow at all the continuity. How did we even assign a norm?

Comment: In Hatcher's book I can't find the maps $A_l$ and $A_f$. Why did you introduce them?

Comment: Those are what I see as the "transition functions", and I find it helpful to think of it this way like you previously recommended. I think I have came up with a local argument using this method. Otherwise, how would you define the homotopy? I think the easiest would be to define 
$$ l(1-t)+tf $$ 

but then how does one show this is continuous when there is no norm etc? This is what the proof in the second link does. I don't see how the norm suddenly comes in. I will type up my solution tomorrow, but I would be more happy to see how you write out, which will be, as always, really helpful.

Comment: @PaulFrost, I have posted my proof, and it essentially uses trivial locality and transition functions. I hope it is right and would be happy for any advice on improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hatcher considers the set $\text{End}(E \times S^1)$ of all bundle endomorphism on $E \times S^1$ and endows it with a norm $\lVert - \rVert$. He then states that the subspace $\text{Aut}(E \times S^1)$ of all bundle automorphism on $E \times S^1$ is open in this normed linear space. Given any two $f_0, f_1 \in \text{End}(E \times S^1)$, the linear path $u : I \to \text{End}(E \times S^1), u(t) = (1-t)f_0 + t f_1,$ is continuous. If $f_0,f_1$ belong to $\text{Aut}(E \times S^1)$, then $u$ may leave $\text{Aut}(E \times S^1)$, but if they are *sufficiently close* (which means that they are contained in a sufficiently small open $\lVert - \rVert$-ball), then $u$ will stay in $\text{Aut}(E \times S^1)$. Taking the adjoint of $u$ provides a function $u^* :E \times S^1 \times I \to E \times S^1$ which is the desired homotopy provided it is continuous. In fact Hatcher has a gap at this point: He doesn't prove the continuity of $u^*$.

We can regard $\text{End}(E \times S^1)$ as a subset of the function space $(E \times S^1)^{E \times S^1}$ endowed with the compact open-topology. If we would know that the compact-open topology on $\text{End}(E \times S^1)$ is coarser than the norm-topology, then also $u : I \to \text{End}(E \times S^1) \hookrightarrow (E \times S^1)^{E \times S^1}$ would be continuous and we could conclude that $u^*$ is continuous because $E \times S^1$ is locally compact (note that $X$ is assumed to be compact).

I am quite optimistic that this can be shown, and I believe the norm topology even agrees with the compact-open topology. However, I shall not further pursue this.

Comment: The proof on p. 63 of https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/162450/files/karpova.semestre.hess2.pdf seems to be not correct (it works with a norm on $E \times S^1$).

Comment: Actually, for $E$ to be locally compact, I believe we need $X$ to compact Hausdorff? otherwise being compact alone wouldn't imply locally compact.

Comment: For $E$ being locally compact It is sufficient to assume that $X$ is locally compact. However, Hatcher only considers compact Hausdorff $X$:

Comment: I actually could not figure out the claim that these topologies coincide. I have open another post, as this chat is getting to messy, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927836/norm-topology-and-compact-open-topology-coincide-for-vector-bundles . It would be great if you could outline the key steps.

Comment: Already answered by user10354138.

Comment: Just saw it, I actually find it rather unclear...

Comment: By the way: It is of course interesting in its own right that the norm topology agrees with the compact-open topology. But we do not really need this See my second answer to the present question..

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I came up. I am happy for any criticism.

**(I) Some properties of transition functions:**

We observe $p \times 1: E \times S^1 \rightarrow X \times S^1$ is a vector bundle. Locally, there are open subsets $U \subseteq X, V \subseteq S^1$, and homeomorphism charts, 
$$h : p^{-1}(U) \times V \rightarrow (U \times V) \times \mathbb C^n .$$

**A clutching function induces a collection of transition function:**
For simplicity, let $U':=U \times V$. So the map $$hlh^{-1}:U' \times \mathbb C^n \rightarrow U' \times \mathbb C^n, (x,v) \mapsto (x,A_l(x)v)$$ 
is a continuous function, where $A_l: U' \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is a continuous map. This can be seen by choosing a basis of $\mathbb C$, and note that each component of $A_l$ is given by the composition 
$$ (u,e_j) \mapsto (u,A_l(u)e_j) \mapsto \pi_i(A_l(u)e_j), \pi_i:\mathbb C^n \rightarrow \mathbb C$$

---

**(II) Constructing homotopy**
Now for defining the homotopy $E \times S^1 \times I \rightarrow E \times S$. We may explicitly define the map as 
$$ (x,t) \mapsto l(x)(1-t)+tf(x).$$ 
To show continuity of this map we break it down locally. Fix a cover of base space $X$, $\{U_i \times S^1 \}$. Fix some $U$ in the cover. Then we have  transition functions $A_l, A_f:U \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb C)$. we first define 
$$g: U \times S^1 \times I \times \mathbb C^n \rightarrow U \times  S^1 \times \mathbb C^n, (x,z,v) \mapsto (x,z, (A_l(x,z)(1-t)+tA_f(x,z))v) $$

This map is continuous as we argued in **(I)**, noting that component why it is a polynomial function of $t$ and components of matrix (which we have previously shown is continuous), hence continuous.

Hence our map can be broken as follows, 
$$ \pi^{-1}(U) \times S^1 \times I \xrightarrow{h} U \times S^1 \times I \times \mathbb {C^n} \xrightarrow{g} U \times S^I \times \mathbb C^n \xrightarrow{h^{-1}} \pi^{-1}(U) \times S^1.$$

which is continuous.

---

**(III) A summary**  Essentially the proof uses locality - and that we can transport the structure to two data:

1. a transition function $U \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb C)$, which is continuous.
2. A map between vector space $U \times \mathbb C^n \rightarrow U \times \mathbb C^n$.

2'. When chosen with basis, the components of transition matrix is continuous.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Hatcher's  proof is completely different. Since comments are too limited in space I give an answer in which I try to sketch what he does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more answer. Let $\xi = (E,p,X), \eta = (F,q,Y)$ be vector bundles and $(f_i,\varphi) : \xi \to \eta$ be two bundle maps over the same $\varphi : X \to Y$ (see e.g. Husemoller's book; we have $q f_i = \varphi p$ and for each $x \in X$ the map $f_{i,x}$ from the fiber over $x$ to the fiber over $\varphi(x)$ is linear).

Then the fiberwise linear homotopy $H : E \times I \to F, H(v_x,t) = (1-t)f_0(v_x) + tf_1(v_x)$ , where $v_x \in p^{-1}(x)$, is continuous. That is, all bundle maps over the same map on the base spaces are homotopic.

This is obvious for trivial bundles. In the general case we can use local trivializations to see that $H$ is locally continuous and hence continuous. Note that under local trivializations fiberwise linear homotopies are transformed locally to fiberwise linear homotopies between trivial bundles.

Hatcher applies this to the case of bundle maps over $id : X \times S^1 \to X \times S^1$. The interesting point is not that all elements of $\text{End}(E \times S^1)$ are homotopic, but that fiberwise linear homotopies stay in $\text{Aut}(E \times S^1)$ provided $f_0,f_1$ are **sufficiently close** automorphisms. This is why he introduced the norm on $\text{End}(E \times S^1)$. In fact, he uses the *convexity* of norm-balls to assure that the linear homotopy between $f_0$ and $f_1$ stays in $\text{Aut}(E \times S^1)$.

Comment: I feel this is more or less similar to what I have done below? i.e. working locally which simplifies. But I totally agree with the meaning of norm and convexity, which allows us to stay in $Aut(E \times S^1)$, this is not seen in the argument, if I provided my proof.

Comment: Yes, our proofs are equivalent variants of the same idea. You used transition functions and I did it directly, but both proofs use local triviality.

Comment: I have a recent question on the short exact sequence and Tietze extension, on page 52 of Hatchers, there are no satisfying replies yet. I wonder what your thoughts are .